# Merge the results from multiple tables side by side in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables using with I need to make a resulting table.

**Scenario:**

1. The table 'Incoming Sentences' contains the steram of sentences
   flowing in to the database.
2. The table 'tagged_sentences' contains
   the sentences from 'incoming_sentences' which are tagged/labelled by the editor. Sometimes the admin overwrites the label if editor makes any mistake in labelling the data. Admin labelled data is final and considered to be correct.
3. The table 'accounts' contain the user's account level information

Below are the tables with sample information.

**Incoming Sentences**

| id | sentence | market | model_identified_intent | tagged_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd | en_in | alphabets | 12/12/2021 |
| 2 | 1234 | en_in | numeric | 11/13/2021 |
| 3 | a1b2 | en_in | alphaNumeric | 10/14/2021 |
| 4 | efgh | en_in | alphabets | 10/15/2021 |
| 5 | e5f6 | en_in | alphaNumeric | 11/16/2021 |

**Tagged Sentences**

| id | tagger_id | sentence_id | tagger_tagged_intent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 | 1 | alphabets |
| 2 | 32 | 2 | alphabets |
| 3 | 32 | 3 | Numeric |
| 4 | 33 | 2 | Numeric |
| 5 | 33 | 3 | alphaNumeric |

**User Account Table**

| id | user_role | email | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | editor | editor@editor.com | editor123 |
| 33 | admin | admin@admin.com | admin456 |

**Expected Output:**

I want to pull the result as 'total tagged senteces per month' in one column and 'total corrections per month by the admin'. Through which the error rate can be known.

| year-month | total_tagged | Total Error (Corrected by admin) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-11 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-12 | 1 | 0 |

Requesting your help in solving this. I tried the below code. But it isn't working as expected.

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT tggs.id                                       id,
                     tggs.sentence                              AS sentence,
                     tggs.market                                AS market,
                     tggs.prod_identified_intent                AS prod_identified_intent,
                     tggs.tagged_at                             AS tagged_at,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tagged_at) AS rn
              FROM tagging_sentences tggs),
     cte2 AS (SELECT tgds.sentence_id_id AS sentence_id,
                     tgds.tagger_id_id   AS tagger_id,
                     tgds.tagged_intent  AS tagged_intent
              FROM tagged_sentences tgds),
     cte3 AS (SELECT acts.id AS account_id, acts.email AS email, acts.role AS role FROM accounts AS acts),
     cte4 AS (SELECT tggs.tagged_at, COUNT(*) AS count, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY count(*)) AS rn
              FROM tagging_sentences AS tggs
                       JOIN tagged_sentences AS tgds ON tggs.id = tgds.sentence_id_id
                       JOIN accounts acts ON tgds.tagger_id_id = acts.id
              WHERE tgds.tagger_id_id = 33
                AND tgds.sentence_id_id IN (SELECT tagging_sentences.id
                                            FROM tagging_sentences,
                                                 tagged_sentences
                                            WHERE tagged_sentences.tagger_id_id = 32) GROUP BY tagged_at)

SELECT TO_CHAR(cte1.tagged_at, 'YYYY-MM'),
       COUNT(cte1.sentence), cte4.count
FROM cte1
         JOIN cte2 ON cte1.id = cte2.sentence_id
         JOIN cte3 ON cte2.tagger_id = cte3.account_id
         JOIN cte4 ON cte1.rn = cte4.rn
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(cte1.tagged_at, 'YYYY-MM'), TO_CHAR(cte4.tagged_at, 'YYYY-MM'), cte4.count;
```

Comment: Please review your  data and expected output. The data you provide **cannot** generate the expected output. Your output indicates values for the months 2021-10, 2021-11, and 2021-12 however your input contains only data for 2021-12.  You need to revise the expected output, revise or include additional input, or perhaps there is a missing data column.

Comment: @Belayer, My bad! I've edited the datasets to match the expected output. Please review and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started trying to determine just where your initial query went awry, but there are still too many inconsistencies; columns names not defined, tables not defined, etc/ And I was not sure what all the CTEs were for. A couple seem to do nothing bu "convert" a table into a CTE (absolutely not necessary). And to attempt getting  `ROW_NUMBER()` results to match (highly doubtful at any rate). The other issue is the magic numbers (id = 32, 33), what happens when there is another Editor and/or Admin? It just seemed overly complex.  
So with that I undertook a rewrite. First I abandoned the CTE approach and used just simple Joins. An Inner Join between  `Incoming Sentences` and `Tagged Sentences` and an Outer Join between `Tagged Sentences` and `User Accounts`. The twist being 2 Outer Joins, 1 getting *editor* role the other getting *admin* role. Thus removing the dependency on the magic numbers. With these in place the only thing that remained was simple counting: ( see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ec4a4a3b3de80dff7f33314165d346d1) )

```
select date_trunc( 'month', i.tagged_at)   "Year Month" 
     , count(uae.user_role) +  
       count(uaa.user_role)                "Total Tagged" 
     , count(uaa.user_role)                "Total Error (Corrected by admin)"   
  from incoming_sentences    i
  join tagged_sentences t 
         on (t.sentence_id = i.id) 
  left join user_accounts uae
    on (    uae.id = t.tagger_id
        and uae.user_role = 'editor'
       ) 
  left join user_accounts uaa
    on (    uaa.id = t.tagger_id
        and uaa.user_role= 'admin'
       ) 
group by date_trunc( 'month',  i.tagged_at)
order by date_trunc( 'month',  i.tagged_at);
```

Note: Demo includes addition of another Editor and Admin. It also shows the case where editor and admin take action in different month.  

Good luck with it.